# la e no se registra como carácter "numérico" entre a y z

Tags: c++, dev-c++

problema:
en mi código pongo un condicional que analiza una cadena de caracteres, se entra al condicional desde que el carácter de la cadena en especifico sea mayor o igual a 'a' pero menor o igual a z, mas a e se le excluye (pasa eso desde que este incluido con otras letras además también pasa con letras como la s)

la cuestión es que no pasa con las mayúsculas (o como siempre la e se vuelve minúscula no veo el error)

aquí esta el código

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void ConvMl_(char [], int);

int main(){
    char Nombre[32];
    int Len;
    
    cout<< "inserte su nombre completo: ";
    cin.getline(Nombre,32);
    
    Len = strlen(Nombre);
    
    ConvMl_(Nombre, Len);
    
    cout<<Nombre<<endl;
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ConvMl_(char Nombre[], int Len){
    int Arr[Len];
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] == ' '){
            Nombre[i] = '_';
        }   
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] >= 'A' && Nombre[i] <= 'Z'){
            Nombre[i] = tolower(Nombre[i]);
            Arr[i]=1;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] >= 'a' && Nombre[i] <= 'z' && Arr[i] != 1){
            Nombre[i] = toupper(Nombre[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

el resultado seria este:
Entrada: Dydier Ripe
Salida: dYDIeR_rIPe

Comment: No inicializas `Arr`: `Arr[Len] = { 0 };`.

Comment: Ese no es el problema. Porque su programa me da: Antoine Copepe -> aNTOiNE_cOPEPE

Comment: Es decir, su problema no es la "E", como podría verlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema no es con las E, es con porque no inicializas `Arr`. Al poner algo explícitamente, resuelves tu problema.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void ConvMl_(char [], int);

int main(){
    char Nombre[32];
    int Len;
    
    cout<< "inserte su nombre completo: ";
    cin.getline(Nombre,32);
    
    Len = strlen(Nombre);
    
    ConvMl_(Nombre, Len);
    
    cout<<Nombre<<endl;
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ConvMl_(char Nombre[], int Len){
    int Arr[Len] = { 'EsNecesarioInicializarElArray' };
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] == ' '){
            Nombre[i] = '_';
        }   
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] >= 'A' && Nombre[i] <= 'Z'){
            Nombre[i] = tolower(Nombre[i]);
            Arr[i]=1;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] >= 'a' && Nombre[i] <= 'z' && Arr[i] != 1){
            Nombre[i] = toupper(Nombre[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Te das:

```
main.cpp:28:22: warning: character constant too long for its type                                                             
inserte su nombre completo: Antoine Coppepe                                                                                   
aNTOINE_cOPPEPE
```

Si la variable es de tipo referencia, inicializarla puede evitar errores de referencia nula más adelante.

Una variable de cualquier tipo que tenga un valor por defecto no nulo ocupará algo de memoria para almacenar el valor por defecto.

Pero peor, deberías deshacerte de la variable `Arr` por completo. Es usar código no estándar. Los Arrays de Longitud Variable (*Variable Lenght Arrays*, VLAs) no son parte de C++ (aunque algunos compiladores los soportan como una extensión). Pero incluso los que lo hacen (si siguen las reglas de C para los VLAs) probablemente no te permitirían inicializarlos. Tus tres bucles pueden combinarse en uno solo usando sentencias if-else-if, lo que te permite deshacerte de la variable Arr fácilmente. Por ejemplo:

```
void ConvMl_(char Nombre[], int Len){
    
    for(int i=0;i<Len;i++){
        if(Nombre[i] == ' '){
            Nombre[i] = '_';
        } else if(Nombre[i] >= 'A' && Nombre[i] <= 'Z'){
            Nombre[i] = tolower(Nombre[i]);
        } else if(Nombre[i] >= 'a' && Nombre[i] <= 'z' ){
            Nombre[i] = toupper(Nombre[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero lo mejor es probabilament de utilisar std::string o std::transform. Porque es más simple, no más difícil de usar:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  char str[] = "Antoine Copepe";

  std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::begin(str), 
    [](unsigned char const ch) {
      if (std::isspace(ch)) return '_';
      if (std::isupper(ch)) return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(ch));
      if (std::islower(ch)) return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(ch));
      return static_cast<char>(ch);
    });

  std::puts(str);
}
```

No necesitas un array separado y 2 bucles. Simplemente haz todas las conversiones que quieras en un solo bucle.

Comment: muchas gracias ^-^

Comment: @DydierRipe bienvenido a Stackoveflow. Aqui nos dicen “muchas gracias” con un upvote y el mejor con tu aceptación de la respuesta. Suerte en tu viaje en la programación